# How to react to an event triggered by a specific date and time being reached

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, scheduled-tasks

I'm writing an application in C++ using Visual Studio in windows 7. The application is a single page MFC dialog application. I want to have a message box pop up when a certain time and date has been reached. I am using a Date Picker to obtain the specified date that will work as the trigger, and CTime objects to store the current time, and the expected time.

Unfortunately, I don't know where to start looking. Is there an object that sends notifications or messages to the window once a minute, on each minute? If not, is there a specific way I can go about having this accomplished, or suggestions as to where I may start looking?

Edit: Is it possible to calculate how many seconds there are between the current date and the future date and create a separate thread that counts down (with a timer)?

Comment: I'm currently looking into WM_TIMECHANGE and OnTimeChange() functions associated with each other. tested them, but they are not working in the way you would think. As in, I've set breakpoints for when WM_TIMECHANGE has been sent, and it's never being sent, even when the time changes. edit: Turns out it's only sent when an application changes the time.

Comment: WM_TIMECHANGE is raised when you change the system time. It is not for timers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough sketch of the functionality you need to implement to receive timer events:

```
UINT_PTR timerId = NULL;

void OnTimerEvent(HWND, UINT, UINT_PTR id, DWORD)
{
    if (timerId == id)
    {
        // timer action...
    }
}

void StartTimer()
{
    // call OnTimerEvent after 1000 milliseconds
    timerId = SetTimer(NULL, NULL, 1000, &OnTimerEvent);
}

void StopTimer()
{
    KillTimer(NULL, timerId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SetTimer` as suggested by @StackedCrooked. But that wont work if system time is changed. Say, for example, current time is 12:30, and you set it for 12:35, so the `SetTimer` you would set would be for 5 minutes. But, if system time is changed to 12:32, the timer would be triggered someway aroung 12:37, and not at 12:35 !

For this, you may like to use [CreateWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I've come up with a semi-working solution. I set a timer that goes off every second. Every second, using the OnTimer function, I check the current time against the time I got from the user. If they match, then I pop a message box. If they don't, I do nothing. Syntax will come as soon as I finish the application and it does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: That's a bad solution, you are wasting "timer" resources!

Comment: Please explain? And if possible, provide an alternative. This is what works, and I've moved on, but if theres a better way, I'll take it.